# Get the DOMElement container inside React render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After doing something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(<ConfirmForm />, document.getElementById('confirm-form'));
```

how can I obtain the `confirm-form` dom element from inside the `ConfirmForm` element?

Inside the `componentDidMount` method I can do

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentElement
```

but inside the `render` method I can't use `this`.

Thanks

Comment: DOM nodes are unstable inside `render` (they're changing after all), so you shouldn't access them in `render`, but you certainly have access to `this`—otherwise  `this.props` wouldn't work. Get the DOM node in `componentDidMount` and save it off somewhere.

Comment: `render` is unreliable for this. You should use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method, see here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: I was thinking to pass the element id via props on `ReactDOM.render` call.. what do you think about it?

Comment: You could simply do `ReactDOM.render(<ConfirmForm parent='confirm-form'/>, document.getElementById('confirm-form'));` However, in react terms, I cannot think of any valid reason why you would need to access the parent DOM-element directly. Anything you wish to learn about this component is better accessed in react's virtual DOM.